# Why doesn't file read output anything?

Tags: c

In the binary file mydata.dat, I've written a string: "this is a test". That's the full contents of the file. I want to read the string back but I don't see any output. The program runs without error though. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
FILE *f = fopen("mydata.dat", "rb");

char content[100];

while(fread(content, sizeof(content), 1, f) == 1){
    printf("%s", content);
}
fclose(f);
```

Comment: `fread` will not be `== 1` if there are not 100 bytes in the file. For text it is better to open the file with mode `"rt"` and then use `fgets`.

Comment: @Zakir, `content` is a string, but `%c` is used to print _a single `char`_, that won't work.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The file is binary and should be treated as such.

Comment: The term "string" refers to a zero-terminated character array. When you use binary, that idea is out of the window. Moreover, even if you contrive `fread` to work by reading one byte at a time, you have no zero terminator when you pass `content` to `printf`. If that was in the *binary* file the content should have been `"this is a test\0"`.

Comment: @4thSpace, are you sure you want to read _one element_ of size 100 bytes and not some `char`s? Because the second argument is the size of a _single_ element to be read. You should probably swap the second and the third arguments.

Comment: @xing: Doesn't work. You should test your code before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you want to read characters, you should use `fgets()`. Let's say that you really want to use `fread()`.

You must understand that `fread()` returns the number of items read, so in your case it's `0`. Because you ask to `fread()` to read 1 element of 100 bytes... This will always return `0`, if your file has less than 100 bytes. You have swapped the size of an element and the number of elements.

Plus if you want your array to be a valid C string you must put a NULL-terminator byte at the end. Because `fread()` will not do it for you.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *f = fopen("mydata.dat", "rb");

  if (f == NULL) { // Error check
    perror("fopen()");
    return 1;
  }

  char content[100];
  size_t ret;

  // We loop on the file to read 99 bytes at each loop
  // sizeof *content is the size of an element of content
  while ((ret = fread(content, sizeof *content, sizeof content - 1, f)) > 0) {
    content[ret] = '\0'; // We use ret to nul terminate our string
    printf("%s", content);
    fflush(stdout); // flush the standard output
  }

  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane: It doesn't matter since nothing outputs anyway if you try to run this code.

Comment: Is that guaranteed behaviour? The code works for me without `fflush`.

Comment: @WeatherVane "If  the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open ﬁles are closed (hence all output streams are ﬂushed) before program termination. Other paths to program termination,  such  as  calling  the abort function,  need  not  close  all  ﬁles properly." C11§7.21.3

Comment: @4thSpace unless all your "strings" are the exact same length, I recommend that you place the `'\0'` terminator *in the file*. Typically, the file could be a dump of a `struct` with one member having a defined array length greater than actually used - but you will not know how much was used without that terminator.